# Is there a generalization of Faulhaber's formula is sense of summation bounds?

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Well known Faulhaber's formula is stated as

$$\sum _{k=1}^{n}k^{p}=\frac{1}{p+1}\sum _{j=0}^{p}{p+1 \choose j}B_{j}n^{p+1-j}$$

But is there any formula which holds for power sum of the form

$$\sum_{k=s}^{n}k^{p}, \quad s\in\mathbb{Z}?$$

Comment: What if you subtract $\sum _{k=1}^nk^p-\sum _{k=1}^{s-1}k^p$?

Comment: @Phicar note that $s\in\mathbb{Z}$ and can be negative integer smaller than -1, so how can you perform such summation when $s-1<k$ ?

Comment: For $s<0$ you have $\sum_{k=s}^0 k^p=(-1)^p\sum_{k=0}^{-s}(-k)^p$ so you still get the appropriate formula pretty much directly from Faulhaber's formula.